# Storing results from a Postgres query directly into an array in Bash 4?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to run a Postgres query like below and store the results into an array:

```
v2_ids=$(psql $(credstash get database/path/here) -tc "select distinct(user_id) from table where yada yada yada..." )

read -a arr_ids_temp <<< $v2_ids
```

Is there a better way to do this? It seems that read -a only grabs the first result sometimes and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `user_id` is not null or nullable in your table?..

Comment: Yeah user_id is always populated

Answer (score 5):

Refer the following code:

```
IFS=$'\n' res=(`psql -tA database username -c 'select column_name from table_name where blah blah...'`)
```

- We must tell the bash to store the result in array based on '\n' delimiter.
- psql options -tA for removing header/footer etc and removing leading and trailing blanks.

> ${res[0]} contains value of first row and each element in array
>   contains the value of each row respectively.

**Additional tips:**

For taking all data in a row into array,

```
IFS='|' res=(`psql -tA database username -c 'select name1,name2,name3 from table_name where blah blah...'`)
```

- Here I told bash to store the psql result in array based on | delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine, but use `psql` with the options `-A` (unaligned output mode), `-q` (suppress informational output) and `-t` (no column names, headers and footers).

Comment: without distinct delimiter bash will split values by spaces - I think this happens to the OP

Comment: True; spaces in te result will make things much harder.

Comment: But `user_id` doesn't sound like it contains spaces.

Comment: :) true! I have a habit to complicate things

Comment: So psql -Aqt -d is giving this output in the v2_ids variable (good so far):

ac566b6cf34d495c9de4be1d81c42c56
ba8fb335223b4919a8287c963ecd9d85

But then

read -a arr_ids_temp <<< $v2_ids

...is only adding the first one to the array. Getting close though.

Comment: Ah! Looks like readarray solved it

readarray arr_ids_temp <<< $v2_ids